# Android + Parse error when trying saving

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform, hal

I'm doing an App that actually consists in a CRUD.

It happens that after filling a form with information to save, the app just crash and I have no idea why.

This is the log I get:

```
01-02 16:15:59.731 11444-11510/com.reforcointeligente.brainstormapp     E/HAL: SLCODE-loaded class_id=gralloc 
01-02 16:15:59.731 11444-11510/com.reforcointeligente.brainstormapp     E/HAL: SLCODE-loaded name=gralloc 
01-02 16:15:59.731 11444-11510/com.reforcointeligente.brainstormapp E/HAL: SLCODE-loaded prop_name=ro.hardware.gralloc 
01-02 16:15:59.731 11444-11510/com.reforcointeligente.brainstormapp E/HAL: SLCODE-loaded for circle execute 
01-02 16:15:59.731 11444-11510/com.reforcointeligente.brainstormapp E/HAL: SLCODE-hw_module_exists HAL_LIBRARY_PATH2=/vendor/lib64/hw, name=gralloc, subname=mt6735 
01-02 16:15:59.731 11444-11510/com.reforcointeligente.brainstormapp E/HAL: SLCODE-hw_module_exists HAL_LIBRARY_PATH1=/system/lib64/hw, name=gralloc, subname=mt6735 
01-02 16:15:59.732 11444-11510/com.reforcointeligente.brainstormapp E/HAL: SLCODE-hw_module_exists return ENOENT 
01-02 16:15:59.732 11444-11510/com.reforcointeligente.brainstormapp E/HAL: SLCODE-hw_module_exists HAL_LIBRARY_PATH2=/vendor/lib64/hw, name=gralloc, subname=MT6737T 
01-02 16:15:59.732 11444-11510/com.reforcointeligente.brainstormapp E/HAL: SLCODE-hw_module_exists HAL_LIBRARY_PATH1=/system/lib64/hw, name=gralloc, subname=MT6737T 
01-02 16:15:59.732 11444-11510/com.reforcointeligente.brainstormapp E/HAL: SLCODE-hw_module_exists return ENOENT 
01-02 16:15:59.732 11444-11510/com.reforcointeligente.brainstormapp E/HAL: SLCODE-hw_module_exists HAL_LIBRARY_PATH2=/vendor/lib64/hw, name=gralloc, subname=mt6737t 
01-02 16:15:59.732 11444-11510/com.reforcointeligente.brainstormapp E/HAL: SLCODE-hw_module_exists HAL_LIBRARY_PATH1=/system/lib64/hw, name=gralloc, subname=mt6737t 
01-02 16:15:59.732 11444-11510/com.reforcointeligente.brainstormapp E/HAL: SLCODE-loaded HAL id=gralloc path=/system/lib64/hw/gralloc.mt6737t.so 
01-02 16:15:59.732 11444-11510/com.reforcointeligente.brainstormapp I/[MALI][Gralloc]: [+]r_hnd(0x7f7d738220), client(27), share_fd(43)
01-02 16:15:59.732 11444-11510/com.reforcointeligente.brainstormapp D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0x7f7d738220) (w:720 h:1280 s:720 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
```

The app brokes when I call this method:

```
public void onStudentCreated() {
    Student student = new Student();

    EditText studentNameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextStudentName);
    EditText studentAgeEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextStudentAge);
    EditText studentSchoolEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextStudentSchool);
    EditText studentAddressEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextStudentAddress);
    EditText studentParentNameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextStudentParentName);
    EditText studentParentCellphoneEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextStudentParentCellphone);
    EditText studentParentPhoneEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextStudentParentPhone);
    EditText studentParentEmailEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextStudentParentEmail);

    String studentName = studentNameEditText.getText().toString();
    String studentAge = studentAgeEditText.getText().toString();
    String studentSchool = studentSchoolEditText.getText().toString();
    String studentAddress = studentAddressEditText.getText().toString();
    String studentCity = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String studentParentName = studentParentNameEditText.getText().toString();
    String studentParenteCellphone = studentParentCellphoneEditText.getText().toString();
    String studentParentPhone = studentParentPhoneEditText.getText().toString();
    String studentParentEmail = studentParentEmailEditText.getText().toString();

    student.setStudentName(studentName);
    student.setStudentAge(studentAge);
    student.setStudentSchool(studentSchool);
    student.setStudentAddress(studentAddress);
    student.setStudentCity(studentCity);
    student.setStudentParentName(studentParentName);
    student.setStudentParentCellphone(studentParenteCellphone);
    student.setStudentParentPhone(studentParentPhone);
    student.setStudentParentEmail(studentParentEmail);

}
```

And finally, this is my model:

```
@ParseClassName("Student")
public class Student extends ParseObject {

    public String getStudentName() {
        return getString(getStudentNameTitle());
    }

    public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
        put(getStudentNameTitle(), studentName);
    }

    public String getStudentAge() {
        return getString(getStudentAgeTitle());
    }

    public void setStudentAge(String studentAge) {
        put(getStudentAgeTitle(), studentAge);
    }

    public String getStudentAddress() {
        return getString(getStudentAddressTitle());
    }

    public void setStudentAddress(String studentAddress) {
        put(getStudentAddressTitle(), studentAddress);
    }

    public String getStudentCity() {
        return getString(getStudentCityTitle());
    }

    public void setStudentCity(String studentCity) {
        put(getStudentCityTitle(), studentCity);
    }

    public String getStudentSchoolYear() {
        return getString(getStudentSchoolYearTitle());
    }

    public void setStudentSchoolYear(String studentSchoolYear) {
        put(getStudentSchoolYearTitle(), studentSchoolYear);
    }

    public String getStudentSchool() {
        return getString(getStudentSchoolTitle());
    }

    public void setStudentSchool(String studentSchool) {
        put(getStudentSchoolTitle(), studentSchool);
    }

    public String getStudentParentName() {
        return getString(getStudentParentNameTitle());
    }

    public void setStudentParentName(String studentParentName) {
        put(getStudentParentNameTitle(), studentParentName);
    }

    public String getStudentParentPhone() {
        return getString(getStudentParentPhoneTitle());
    }

    public void setStudentParentPhone(String studentParentPhone) {
        put(getStudentParentPhoneTitle(), studentParentPhone);
    }

    public String getStudentParentCellphone() {
        return getString(getStudentParentCellphoneTitle());
    }

    public void setStudentParentCellphone (String studentParentCellphone) {
        put(getStudentParentCellphoneTitle(), studentParentCellphone);
    }

    public String getStudentParentEmail() {
        return getString(getStudentParentEmailTitle());
    }

    public void setStudentParentEmail(String studentParentEmail) {
        put(getStudentParentEmailTitle(), studentParentEmail);
    }

    public static ParseQuery<Student> getQuery() {
        return ParseQuery.getQuery(Student.class);
    }

    public static String getStudentNameTitle() {
        return "nome_aluno";
    }

    private static String getStudentAgeTitle() {
        return "idade_aluno";
    }

    private static String getStudentAddressTitle() {
        return "endereco_aluno";
    }

    private static String getStudentCityTitle() {
        return "cidade_aluno";
    }

    private static String getStudentSchoolYearTitle() {
        return "serie_aluno";
    }

    private static String getStudentSchoolTitle() {
        return "colegio_aluno";
    }

    private static String getStudentParentNameTitle() {
        return "nome_pai_aluno";
    }

    private static String getStudentParentPhoneTitle() {
        return "telefone_pai_aluno";
    }

    private static String getStudentParentCellphoneTitle() {
        return "celular_pai_aluno";
    }

    private static String getStudentParentEmailTitle() {
        return "email_pai_aluno";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, my problem was configurating the Parse. I just gave up and start using firebase wich I find much better 'cause it's easier to set up, simpler to use and have much more documentation.